Email-to-Case Not Producing New Cases
We have an Email-to-Case setup for an email address (itsolutions@ourcompany.com). We have our HR dept send an email to the IT dept upon the hire of new employee in order to initiate the creation of a new Case for that new hire's laptop. The new employee comes from humanresources@ourcompany.com and is sent to the new employee and cc's itsolutions@ourcompany.com.
We also want all replies to the emails to be placed under the newly created Case.
This was working for a while but for some reason it is no longer working. It is now no longer creating a new Case. Instead, it is placing all of the new emails coming from humanresources which should be creating new Cases into an old Case. They are all going into the same Case. No new Case is being produced and for some reason they're all going to email history of the same old Case.
I looked at the Email-to-Case configuration for the routing email. There's nothing special about it.
It's baffling because I can't see anything unique about the Case which all of the cases are going to.
Any ideas/suggestions ? Thank you.

Possible reasons: (1) The from:humanresources email template somehow includes the threading token that matches to the same old case. (2) You have some under-the-covers automation that is merging cases. Look at debug log for the automated case user to gain insight

We've determined that your reason #1 is correct. Once they started not using their old email template the problem stopped. Thank you very much for your input on this. Right now, I'm trying to find the reference they have in the emails they were sending out. Do you happen to know where/what that would be ? Would it be the Case # or the Record ID of the Case in the body of the email ? The reference is invisible. What is the best way of finding it ? Do you know where it would be found in the body or the method of finding it in Outlook ? Thanks again. @cropredy

Depends on whether you have Lightning Threading Tokens enabled (a Release Update) or are still using the legacy REF ID tokens (this assumes you have no special automation that is intercepting EmailMessage and reparenting it to a specific Case (if so, then a CaseNumber or recordId could be somewhere in the text body (you might have to look at the EmailMessage.TextBody field to see it
